AutoMapper - EF Core: reuse entity in navigation property
I got to refactor some existing code and there I hit a scenario I need to resolve using AutoMapper and EF Core. There are business and entity objects, for example:
class BusinessMaster
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public BusinessRef {get;set;}
}
class BusinessRef
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
}
...
class EntityMaster
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string RefId {get;set;}
  public EntityRef Ref {get;set;}
}
class EntityRef
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
}

The Ref domain is independent of the Master, the Master just can use existing Ref object.
Then the question is - how should be the AutoMapper map BusinessMaster -> EntityMaster set properly? If I have an object of BusinessMaster that references an instance of BusinessRef, I want to map the BusinessMaster to EntityMaster (obviously) and also the BusinessRef to the EntityRef BUT I need to be sure the EntityRef instance is the already existing EF Core tracked instance and if I try to add a new instance of EntityMaster to the DB through the EF it does not try to insert also a new record for the EntityRef.
I know I can use the overload on the root level, aka
mapper.Map<EntityMaster>(businessMaster, existingEntityMaster);

But I need something like that for the internal references.

Just don't map the Ref instance but use its Id to set RefId property (ForMember + MapFrom).
